# Merge Two List of Map in Java and create 3rd Map?

Tags: java, java-8

I really need assistance in solving the below

I have two `List<Map<String, Object>> map1` and `List<Map<String, Object>> map2`, I need to combine two Map to create the `List<Map<String, Object>> map3`. I am really struggling to make it working. Any real quick help ?

Data to work with ?
1st Map

```
[{ACC_NUM=4973, PARENT_ACC_ID=7896, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO}, 
{ACC_NUM=5464, PARENT_ACC_ID=5464, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO}, 
{ACC_NUM=8313, PARENT_ACC_ID=5902, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO}, 
{ACC_NUM=8693, PARENT_ACC_ID=1268, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO}, 
{ACC_NUM=12175, PARENT_ACC_ID=12175, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO}]
```

2nd Map

```
[{COUNT=2, PRNT_ACC_NUM=5464}, {COUNT=2, PRNT_ACC_NUM=1268}, {COUNT=5, PRNT_ACC_NUM=5902}, {COUNT=1, PRNT_ACC_NUM=7896}]
```

create 3rd Map

```
[{ACC_NUM=4973, PARENT_ACC_ID=7896, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO, **COUNT=1**}, 
{ACC_NUM=5464, PARENT_ACC_ID=5464, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO, **COUNT=2**}, 
{ACC_NUM=8313, PARENT_ACC_ID=5902, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO, **COUNT=5**}, 
{ACC_NUM=8693, PARENT_ACC_ID=1268, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO, **COUNT=2**}, 
{ACC_NUM=12175, PARENT_ACC_ID=12175, CRTE_DT=2017-06-22 , PURCH_DT=null, CRTE_USER_ID=ZZZ, IN_CHANGED=NO}]
```

Code

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("ACC_NUM", 4973);
    map1.put("PARENT_ACC_ID", 7896);
    map1.put("CRTE_DT", 2017-06-22);
    map1.put("PURCH_DT", null);
    map1.put("CRTE_USER_ID", "ZZZ");
    map1.put("IN_CHANGED", "NO");

    Map<String, Object> map12 = new HashMap<>();
    map12.put("ACC_NUM", 5464);
    map12.put("PARENT_ACC_ID", 5464);
    map12.put("CRTE_DT", 2017-06-22);
    map12.put("PURCH_DT", null);
    map12.put("CRTE_USER_ID", "ZZZ");
    map12.put("IN_CHANGED", "NO");

    List<Map<String, Object>> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    l1.add(map1);
    l1.add(map12);

    Map<String, Object> map21 = new HashMap<>();
    map21.put("COUNT", 2);
    map21.put("PRNT_ACC_NUM", 7896);

    Map<String, Object> map22 = new HashMap<>();
    map22.put("COUNT", 2);
    map22.put("PRNT_ACC_NUM", 7896);

    List<Map<String, Object>> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    l2.add(map21);
    l2.add(map22);
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? What's going wrong with what you've tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried using [`Map.putAll(Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) or [`Map.merge(Object,Object,BiFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction))?

Comment: @shmosel - Its not duplicate and that answer doesnot works

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: Did you try to run code ? Did it work for you?

Comment: @Prateek try this guy -->  `List<Map<String, Object>> map3 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.forEach(map -> {
            Map<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<>(map);
            temp.put("COUNT", l2.stream()
                               .filter(m -> m.containsValue(map.get("PARENT_ACC_ID")))
                               .findFirst().map(c -> c.get("COUNT")).orElse("SomeDefaultValue......"));
            map3.add(temp);
        });`